# Can someone tell me what is this template

Tags: joomla-2.5

I want to ask what is name of template on these two sites:
ukraina.ru & elpiadis.com

I'm searching for the name of their templates for a few months now.

Comment: Sorry 
i want to ask what is name of this theme*

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Nemanja. Please take the [site tour](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [documentation](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help). This is not a forum, it's a Q&A site. Good questions will receive good answers. (And bumping your post is not correct). @Lodder already answered your question, there's nothing more to know about the template. They probably built the template from scratch, or based it loosely on a framework or another template. Using existing templates and change the name is not the only way to make a personalized template.

Comment: http://www.elpiadis.com/templates/elpiadis/templateDetails.xml contains email and website address for the author of the template.

Answer (score 1):

The first site you provided is not a Joomla site, therefore knowing the template nearly impossible. They have have built it themselves.

The second site you provided is a Joomla site, and the template name is **elpiadis**, so they have built this themselves.

Comment: The templates are same, so second site template is elpadis like site name, so another template is by original maded and only the name is replaced.